# Grid System Horizontal Order

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, grid

Is there any way I can accomplish the following order without adding any div's?

**t1  t2  t3**

**d1  d2  d3**

```
<dl>
<dt>t1</dt>
<dd>d1</dd>
<dt>t2</dt>
<dd>d2</dd>
<dt>t3</dt>
<dd>d3</dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without adding divs I would add the grid system ordering, like this:

```
<dl class="row">
 <dt class="col-4 order-1">t1</dt>
 <dd class="col-4 order-4">d1</dd>
 <dt class="col-4 order-2">t2</dt>
 <dd class="col-4 order-5">d2</dd>
 <dt class="col-4 order-3">t3</dt>
 <dd class="col-4 order-6">d3</dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply display the parent element to grid

```
display: grid;
```

And apply peropery below that

```
grid-auto-flow: dense;
```

Or you can use

```
grid-auto-flow: column dense 1fr;
```